# Large Data GridView Show All Row Numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in asp.net. I have a large data. I want to show in gridview with paging. I can bind datas with OnPageIndexChanging. This is bind just partial data row numbers on pager.
My question is show all data row numbers.

Current result:
1-2-3-4-...

I want to this result:
1-2-3-4-...-100-...-200-...-5000

**My code:**

```
<asp: GridView
      runat="server"
      ID="gridRaporLog"
      CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped"
      OnPageIndexChanging="gridRaporLog_PageIndexChanging"
      AllowPaging="true"
      PageSize="5">
    <PagerSettings Mode="Numeric"
                   PageButtonCount="4"
                   FirstPageText="First"
                   LastPageText="Last" / >
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-ys" / >
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your mode to NumericFirstLast. See below code

```
<PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="4"  FirstPageText="First"LastPageText="Last"/>
```

Here is the reference. [Click Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/pagersetting-modes-in-Asp-Net-gridview-control/)

**EDIT**

To show number instead of LAST, you have to write below code at server side

```
GridView1.PagerSettings.FirstPageText = "1";
GridView1.PagerSettings.LastPageText = "" + GridView1.PageCount + "";
```

Comment: Thank you Gagan. But this isn't my solution. Sample, I am bind 1000 row record. Then I have 20 page number. I have 5000 row record and I want to show 100 page number. I am talking about large data binding.

Comment: Do you mean that instead of "Last" you want to show 20 and 100 respectively for your example. correct?

Comment: @egvrcn I have edited the answer. I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: @gagan You didn't specify where to add the code at the server side.